# Draw a card when my deck and my discard piles are empty

Tags: ascension

There are some times in Ascension when I managed to empty my deck by drawing all the cards in it and also all the cards in the discard piles. It happened once or twice that I played a card that makes me draw another card. Are there special rules to cover this case, or do I simply ignore the drawing effect of the card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply skip the draw part of the instruction.

[According to Justin Gary](http://stoneblade.com/board/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=46#p253), one of the designers of the game:

> If you have to draw a card and none are available in your deck or discard pile, you simply skip the draw.